# Displaying logged in user name

Tags: php

I'm trying to show the User's Name in a login button at the top of our page. I tried to base it off of this advice, but it's just showing the PHP code. Specifically, I'd like "My Account" to change to "Welcome {UserName}.
[How do I display logged-in username IF logged-in?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49686/how-do-i-display-logged-in-username-if-logged-in?newreg=7cf79dbb3f07478e91c161ebe9afe4c4)

```
                <?php global $current_user; wp_get_current_user(); ?>
                <?php if (!is_user_logged_in()) :?>
                    <a href="/member-login/" class="login">Member Login</a>
                <?php else : ?>

                <a href="/account-page/" class="login">My Account</a>

                <?php endif; ?>
                <a href="/membership/join-sccap-renew-membership/"  class="join">Join</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer in your link is correct. If it's just showing PHP code then your code isn't between PHP tags `<?php` & `?>`.

```
<?php if (!is_user_logged_in()) :?>
    <a href="/member-login/" class="login">Member Login</a>
<?php else : ?>
    <a href="/account-page/" class="login">Welcome <?php echo $current_user->display_name; ?></a>
<?php endif; ?>

<a href="/membership/join-sccap-renew-membership/"  class="join">Join</a>
```

Comment: it is also possible that you are not entering the code into a php template...