# Paid Membership Pro displaying a user name in PHP

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, customization

I am using the plugin [Paid Membership Pro (free version)](https://wordpress.org/plugins/paid-memberships-pro/). Just below the header, if a user is logged into my site I would like it to say:

> Welcome *Username*

How could I do this?

This is how to get the membership level:

```php
if(
    is_user_logged_in()
    && function_exists('pmpro_hasMembershipLevel')
    && pmpro_hasMembershipLevel()
) {
    global $current_user;
    $current_user->membership_level = pmpro_getMembershipLevelForUser($current_user->ID);
    echo 'Membership Level: ' . $current_user->membership_level->name;
}
```

How do I use that to display username instead of membership level?

Many Thanks,

Paul

Comment: Look at [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49686/how-do-i-display-logged-in-username-if-logged-in?newreg=7cf79dbb3f07478e91c161ebe9afe4c4)

Answer (score 0):

Following @nmr's comment, you can try this:

```php
if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    global $current_user;
    echo 'Hello, ' . esc_html( $current_user->display_name );
}
```

Comment: `pmpro_hasMembershipLevel()` is not needed to display the username.

Comment: Thanks @nmr - I just glazed over that bit, d'oh!